# Access Denied read open data into Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker, opendata

Cannot read AWS open data datasets into Sagemaker. Error is

```
download failed: s3://fast-ai-imageclas/cifar100.tgz to ../../../tmp/fastai-images/cifar100.tgz An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

code
[image: sagemaker notebook s3 download access denied]

The user has the s3:getObjects * permission

The user's permissions are the full s3 read policy and the full Sagemaker policies. The policies are

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScheduledAction",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "aws-marketplace:ViewSubscriptions",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "codecommit:BatchGetRepositories",
                "codecommit:CreateRepository",
                "codecommit:GetRepository",
                "codecommit:ListBranches",
                "codecommit:ListRepositories",
                "cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup",
                "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminDeleteUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminRemoveUserFromGroup",
                "cognito-idp:CreateGroup",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPoolDomain",
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:ListGroups",
                "cognito-idp:ListIdentityProviders",
                "cognito-idp:ListUserPoolClients",
                "cognito-idp:ListUserPools",
                "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
                "cognito-idp:ListUsersInGroup",
                "cognito-idp:UpdateUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:UpdateUserPoolClient",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:Describe*",
                "elastic-inference:Connect",
                "glue:CreateJob",
                "glue:DeleteJob",
                "glue:GetJob",
                "glue:GetJobRun",
                "glue:GetJobRuns",
                "glue:GetJobs",
                "glue:ResetJobBookmark",
                "glue:StartJobRun",
                "glue:UpdateJob",
                "groundtruthlabeling:*",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/*sagemaker*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codecommit:GitPush"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:*:*:*sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:codecommit:*:*:*SageMaker*",
                "arn:aws:codecommit:*:*:*Sagemaker*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:CreateSecret",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
                "secretsmanager:TagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/SageMaker": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "robomaker:CreateSimulationApplication",
                "robomaker:DescribeSimulationApplication",
                "robomaker:DeleteSimulationApplication"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "robomaker:CreateSimulationJob",
                "robomaker:DescribeSimulationJob",
                "robomaker:CancelSimulationJob"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*SageMaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*Sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*aws-glue*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/SageMaker": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*SageMaker*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*Sagemaker*",
                "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*LabelingFunction*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_SageMakerEndpoint",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "sagemaker.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "robomaker.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
                        "glue.amazonaws.com",
                        "robomaker.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Sagemaker instance is in us-east-1 same as the dataset.

The dataset is https://registry.opendata.aws/fast-ai-imageclas/

Comment: Is above the Sagemaker Execution Role assigned to the notebook, or the role for the User accessing the console? Is there a reason you couldn't use the managed policy arn:aws:iam::282942359435:policy/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-20181214T122803 ?

Comment: the above policies are on the IAM user I used to create the Sagemaker notebook instance. I don't know how to use the managed policy you listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to Matthew I looked into the permissions of the notebook itself, not just the user using Sagemaker.

The policies on the notebook look like this and I can download from the aws open data datasets!

[image: notebook settings]

[image: notebook permissions]